# How to get objects in array of object in React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, react-native

I'm kind of lost to access some info in my static data. Here's the data :

```
{
 "info1": {
    "label": "label",
    "class": "class-css",
    "title": "title",
    "text": "text",
    "number": "20",
    "tags": [
         {
            "name": "#twitter"
        },
        {
            "name": "#myspace"
        }
    ]
 },
 "info2": {
    "label": "label",
    "class": "class-css",
    "title": "title",
    "text": "text",
    "number": "20",
    "tags": [
         {
            "name": "#instagram"
        },
        {
            "name": "#facebook"
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then I get the first info like that :

```
this.setState({
    currentLabel: this.state.labels["info1"]
})
```

This is why I want and then I want to display info in a component and it's working until I try to get `tags` information. I tried a `.map()` but without success and error.

```
<View>
   <Text>{infoDetail.title}</Text>
   <Text>{infoDetail.text}</Text>
   <Text>How do I get "tags" information</Text>
</View>
```

Is it possible to access these objects in the array "tags" ?

Comment: Can you please share the code that you have tried with `.map`, I tried your JSON with `.map` and it worked just fine.

Comment: If I tried this and I have "undefined" :
`const tagsItems = this.state.currentLabel.tags.map((tag, index) => {
            return <Text key={index}>{tag.name}</Text>
        })`

If I do it like this, it's working :
`const tagsItems = this.state.labels["r1"].tags.map((tag, index) => {
   return <Text key={index}>{tag.name}</Text>
})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a full working code. Since your `labels` state property is an object, you need to map it somehow. I've chosen `Object.values` here. You can use `Object.keys` or even `Object.entries` according to your needs.

I've used a separate `Info` component and passed the values to it, then render there. In this component, we are again mapping the `tags`, then rendering the list.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    labels: {
      info1: {
        label: "label1",
        class: "class-css",
        title: "title",
        text: "text",
        number: "20",
        tags: [
          {
            name: "#twitter",
          },
          {
            name: "#myspace",
          },
        ],
      },
      info2: {
        label: "label2",
        class: "class-css",
        title: "title",
        text: "text",
        number: "20",
        tags: [
          {
            name: "#instagram",
          },
          {
            name: "#facebook",
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  }

  render() {
    const { labels } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {
          Object.values( labels ).map( value =>
            <Info label={value} key={value.label} /> )
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Info = ( props ) => {
  const { title, text, tags } = props.label;
  const tagList = tags.map( tag => <p key={tag.name}>{tag.name}</p> );
  return (
    <div style={{ border: "1px solid gray", marginTop: "-1px" }}>
      <p>{title}</p>
      <p>{text}</p>
      <div>{tagList}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Update**

If your data is totally static then @Xavi A.'s method is a good option. I don't know how is your list but I provide a simple code including something like you want here.

```js
const labels = {
  info1: {
    label: "label1",
    class: "class-css",
    title: "title",
    text: "text",
    number: "20",
    tags: [
      {
        name: "#twitter"
      },
      {
        name: "#myspace"
      }
    ]
  },
  info2: {
    label: "label2",
    class: "class-css",
    title: "title",
    text: "text",
    number: "20",
    tags: [
      {
        name: "#instagram"
      },
      {
        name: "#facebook"
      }
    ]
  }
};

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    currentLabel: Object.keys(labels)[0]
  };

  handleInfoChange = info => this.setState({ currentLabel: info });

  renderList = () => (
    <ul>
      {Object.keys(labels).map(info => (
        <Item key={info} info={info} onClick={this.handleInfoChange} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );

  render() {
    const { currentLabel } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderList()}
        <Info currentLabel={currentLabel} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Item = props => {
  const { info, onClick } = props;
  const handleClick = () => onClick(info);
  return <li onClick={handleClick}>{info}</li>;
};

const Info = props => {
  const { currentLabel } = props;
  const { title, text, tags } = labels[currentLabel];
  const tagList = tags.map(tag => <p key={tag.name}>{tag.name}</p>);
  return (
    <div style={{ border: "1px solid gray", marginTop: "-1px" }}>
      <p>{title}</p>
      <p>{text}</p>
      <div>{tagList}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render( <App />, document.getElementById( "root" ) );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: It works but it displays all the data and not only the first one (the current/selected label) but thank you it's a good example that I can follow !!

Comment: You are welcome. So, is there a list you can select? Something can be written according to this case of course.

Comment: the case is : I have this list with "info1, info2, ... and more". I want the first item selected and then I will manipulate the state with a onPress on several elements to switch between info1 or info4, or info5 ... `currentLabel` will change ;-)

Comment: Ok, is your data totally static or do you get it from somewhere else asynchronously?

Comment: thank you @devserkan. I completely understood now! Everything is working fine.
So, finally, I'm using `this.setState({currentLabel: Object.values(labelsInfo)[0]})`, ... and I even can `.map()` my `tags`. So cool. You know, I'm stil learning and sometimes I don't understand what I'm doing and sometimes things worked and I don't remember how :-)

Comment: In this case, it's totally a static data. I have other components with `API` Call with `Axios` but it's working. Thanks again

Comment: You are welcome. If anything is blurry, don't hesitate to ask here. I can explain a little bit more. If you are new I strongly advise [React's official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html). For other things like `map`, `Object.keys` let [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) be your friend, a close one :)

Answer (score 4):

yes you can call tags as follows infoDetail.tags and do map on it

```
render(){
      const tagItems = infoDetail && infoDetail.tags.map((item, index) => {
          return <Text key={index}>{item.name}</Text>
      });
      return(
        <View>
          <Text>{infoDetail.title}</Text>
          <Text>{infoDetail.text}</Text>
          {tagItems}
        </View>
      )
}
```

Comment: The fact is I'm using a Functional (Stateless) Component so I pass my props: 

`<LabelDetail infoDetail={this.state.currentLabel} />`

then I use infoDetail to display every info.. but `map()` doesn't work

Comment: First you need to check whether infoDetail really has data or not and then only do map on it. Since you shared only pieces of code I just advised you about how you can do map on it and display. So you need to do conditional check because doing map. I Updated my answer please have a look you will understand

Answer (score 3):

Probably something like this.
`<Text>{infoDetail.tags.map(tag => {/*render */})}</Text>`

Answer (score 2):

You can try `Object.keys()` and `Array.prototype.reduce()` to get your favorite data:

```js
const data = {
 "info1": {
    "label": "label",
    "class": "class-css",
    "title": "title",
    "text": "text",
    "number": "20",
    "tags": [
         {
            "name": "#twitter"
        },
        {
            "name": "#myspace"
        }
    ]
 },
 "info2": {
    "label": "label",
    "class": "class-css",
    "title": "title",
    "text": "text",
    "number": "20",
    "tags": [
         {
            "name": "#instagram"
        },
        {
            "name": "#facebook"
        }
    ]
  }
};

const tags = Object.keys(data).reduce((result, key) => {
  return result.concat(data[key].tags);
}, [])

console.log(tags);

/* tags = [
  {
    "name": "#twitter"
  },
  {
    "name": "#myspace"
  },
  {
    "name": "#instagram"
  },
  {
    "name": "#facebook"
  }
] */
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to save all the static data in your state, you can keep your state cleaner by just saving the selected label:

```
onLabelSelect = label => {
    //label will be "info1" for example
    this.setState({
        currentLabel: label 
    })
}
```

Then in your render:

```
render(){ 
    //get infoDetail from staticData 
    const infoDetail = staticData[this.state.currentLabel]         
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{infoDetail.title}</Text>
            <Text>{infoDetail.text}</Text>
            {infoDetail.tags.map( ({name}) => <Text>name</Text>)}
        </View>
    )
}
```

Note about the map. This:

`{infoDetail.tags.map( ({name}) => <Text>name</Text>)}`

is a shorter version of:

```
{infoDetail.tags.map( item => {
    return <Text>item.name</Text>
})}
```